# asp-for tag helper functionality

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, tag-helpers

I know that `asp-for` tag helper for an `<input>` sets the `name` attribute, so that it can be bound to model class. e.g. `asp-for="Movie.Year"` when retrieving data from a POST request...

In another scenario (probably GET request): does `asp-for` also extract each `<input>`s value from the model class instance and fill the `value` attribute based on it after instantiation through the PageModel-derived class.

e.g.

```
<input asp-for="Movie.Price" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: `asp-for` sets the `id`, `name` and validation related attributes, and it also sets the *value* of the input element if there is already a value within the model passed to the view – if that’s what you are asking.

Comment: The value comes from `ModelState`, which is composed from `Request`, `ViewData`/`ViewBag`, and `Model`. `Model` is the last source, so anything from the request or `ViewData` will override any value on the model.

Comment: yes, `asp-for` will bind the object value to the input field with `GET` request. just do a simple test to see it in action :)