# How to prevent old data in Model from being passed into the input fields automatically?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Is it possible to prevent the data from being automatically passed to the input fields. For example - if I have an edit page where I want to change the data and I want the user to type the data again without giving him the pre-filled old data. I was looking over some documentation about the ModelState and the asp-for tag but I just couldn't find the answer.

I was looking for help and I found this post here. Well I want to do exactly the opposite.

[asp-for tag helper functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57394092/asp-for-tag-helper-functionality#_=)_

EDIT:
I tried to change the value attribute of the input field to empty string and it worked, however I still would like to know if there is an asp.net approach.

Comment: You have to post your model,  view and actions

Comment: For some reason it is totally not possible to do so. I am trying to edit the post and insert the code but it throws an error saying I am not inserting the code right and I yes, I read the how it's done but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to pass data from action to Edit view,you can return a view with an empty model like this:

```
public IActionResult Edit()
        {
            return View(new YourModel());
        }
```

Or you can try to use `id` and `name` attribute to replace `asp-for`,so that the data will not be binded to inputs.Here is a demo.

Change

```
<input asp-for="TestProperty" />
```

to

```
<input id="TestProperty" name="TestProperty" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much! As I am new to .NET Core I suppose that after I do this I can just create a new object inheriting the id of the original one and then update it in the database. (Id is my Primary key so I guess it should work,  shouldn't it?)

Comment: Yes,you can update it.